# Preparing 2d plots for publication

Tags: plotting, ticks

When it comes to plotting a data my general attitude is to avoid post processing (say with adobe illustrator) as much as possible. To follow this strategy I would like to prepare **publication-ready** pdf plots with *Mathematica*. Here are my requirements

- Plotted lines should have width of **exactly 1pt**.
- The same should be true for the lines forming axes, frames, ticks.
- The ticks have a commensurate length. I find it is optically pleasing to have **major ticks of 4pt** lengths.
- The graph should have a dimension of one column, i.e. ~ **8.5cm** or 240pt.
- All the tick labels, axes labels, etc. should be done with **12pt Helvetica**.
- No white background.

One can argue about the art value of this setup. I, personally, find it is a good compromise between the visibility and simplicity. I remember these numbers and keep them the same across different programs and publications.

I tried to develop very easy solution that can be kept in mind. Since there is a known problem with tick length (it cannon be set explicitly) I decided to adjust the rest of parameters to this dimension. At first step I am just plotting the function

```
fx[x_] := 1/(Exp[-x - 7] + 1) + 1/(Exp[x - 7] + 1) - 1
```

with default settings and nice blue-apple color

```
blue = RGBColor[17.6/100, 41.6/100, 63.1/100];
u = Plot[fx[x], {x, -15, 15}, 
      PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "fx(x)"}, 
      PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[0.5], blue]]
```

The absolute thickness was set to 0.5pt because I am going to enlarge the graph on the second step:

```
Show[u, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[0.5], 6, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
  ImageSize -> 120]
Export[FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "u1.pdf"}], %]
```

As you see the graph has now the horizontal dimension of 120pt, i.e. 50% of the desired result. But I tolerate this since it is a vector graphics. All lines have the right thickness of 50%$\times$1pt=0.5pt and major ticks are of 50%$\times$4pt=2pt. The font sizes are also right: 50%$\times$12pt=6pt.

The only problem in present approach is wrong placement of some tick labels. Numbers -10 and 10 are vertically misaligned:

[image]

I would appreciate any help on this particular issue, or, on the production of publication ready graphs in general. I explicitly decline possibilities of drawing ticks manually, using additional packages or post processing. **Please, feel free to criticise my artistic style.**

**Update**

I would like to make some comments on my approach. The whole idea comes from the fact that it is unacceptable for me to use additional packages for very simple plots. At the same time I have **very modest requirements** on graphics parameters for visual appeal. Crucial parameters for me are the lines' thickness and the ticks' length. Since there is no simple way to set the ticks' length explicitly I am forced to rescale the image. That is, the image of 240pt is required, however, it is prepared at 120pt. Everything would be perfect provided ticks' labels are properly placed.

Comment: Sidenote: Did you take a look at the [LevelScheme package](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/)? The included [`CustomTicks`](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/CustomTicksGuide.pdf) package may come in handy for high-quality plots.

Comment: I have looked at the LevelScheme package. I am not happy with this solution because it relies on additional packages and because I feel such simple thing as the 2d plot such complex software as mathematica should manage on its own.

Comment: In what way is there "wrong placement of some ticks?"  Do you want the negative sign not to affect the centering of the digit characters?

Comment: The numbers "-10" and "10" should be vertically aligned with "-15", "-5", etc.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I ment tick labels not ticks. Now it is corrected. Thank you for this remark!

Comment: Ah, I didn't seven see that misalignment at first glance.  Strange problem.  I'm trying to remember if this has come up before.

Comment: They are aligned properly on 9.01 on Win 7... what OS/viewer setup do you have?

Comment: It seems like an unsatisfactory solution to make thicknesses half the actually desired value and then to scale the entire figure. Surely this creates fuzzy figures.

Comment: ... and your save path will not work in general - perhaps better use `Export["u1.pdf",...]` here?

Comment: My mathematica is 9.0.1.0, Platform Mac OS X 10.9.2

Comment: @ Yves Klett: You are right about the path. Desktop might be not available on some os.

Comment: I dimly seem to remember rendering issues with different viewers on OS X (but cannot find it). ... here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40287/131, but does not seem directly related.

Comment: @YvesKlett `Export["u1.pdf",..]` doesn't work on Linux (don't know about Mac) returning `Export::noopen: "Cannot open u1.pdf."`. And they are aligned for me on Linux V8.04

Comment: I don't see how this is related, but just in case I'll link: [(2214)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214)

Comment: @ Yves Klett: It is not an issue of the viewer. The graph you see above was converted to png with adobe illustrator. Same look with adobe acrobat and preview.

Comment: @Öskå `$UserDocumentsDirectory`... any better?

Comment: @YvesKlett Much better ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you do things at half-size and say "I am going to enlarge the graph on the second step". When I evaluate your code don't get any enlargement in the PDF file. However, I do see your problem with tick label alignment.

I decided to see what happened if I did the enlargement in *Mathematica*, before exporting.

```
u2 = 
 Magnify[
   Show[u, 
        AxesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[0.5], 6, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
        ImageSize -> 120], 
   2]
Export[FileNameJoin[{HomeDirectory[], "Desktop", "u2.pdf"}], u2]
```

In OS X Preview, I converted the PDF image to PNG with a resolution of 72-points/inch and got the following;

[image: u2.png]

There is no misalignment in the tick labels. Perhaps this can be work-around for you.

#### Update

As I said above, I don't understand your approach. On the other hand, when I do it the naive way

```
u = 
  Plot[fx[x], {x, -15, 15}, PlotRange -> All, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "fx(x)"}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], blue],
    AxesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], 12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"],
    ImageSize -> 240]
Export[FileNameJoin[{HomeDirectory[], "Desktop", "u2.pdf"}], u]
```

I get a PDF document with the image having the precise dimensions you specify (240 x 164.35 pts). The lines are 1 pt thick and the major ticks are 4 pts. The text is rendered at 12-pt height. I don't understand why you reject doing it this way.

Comment: And that is exactly my problem. It just looks ugly. All sizes are wrong. I repeated your recipe and that is what I got: 1) the width of the graph **172.8** pt instead of 120 or 240pt. 2)The major ticks have length **1.808** pt and width **0.72** pt with the ratio **2.5:1** instead **4:1** . If I scale your pdf output to desired 240pt width I get the ticks and line width of correct 1pt. However, as I said, the ticks are too short and I find it strange to deal with **8.64pt** fonts!

Comment: I repeated again your recipe, now the updated version. Your claim about the tick's length is not right. The major ticks have dimensions 2.59$\times$1pt. The ratio is almost the same as before, i.e. **2.6:1** !

Comment: @yarchik. I believe you should add 1 pt to account for  the thickness of the axes. I measured from the center of an axis line to the end to a major tick. My point ruler gave 4 pts.

Comment: I measure in the same way. I can imagine the measurement process can be software dependant. In order to avoid extended discussions on the measurement rules try to get major ticks 8pt$\times$1pt in your coordinate system.

Comment: I can confirm yarchik version, I have mathematica 10.0.1 on windows 7 x64 and I get 2.61 pt from the center of the axis to the very left edge of the long tick and 3.13 pt from the very left edge of the axis to the very right edge of the tick, using @m_goldberg's code. For yarchik original version of the code I am getting 2.03 and 2.29 pt.