# Strange filling

Tags: plotting, bugs, version-9, filling

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 10.0**

---

I observed some strange behaviour when plotting a function with filling.

**The code** is as follows:

```
fx[x_] := 1/(Exp[-x - 7] + 1) + 1/(Exp[x - 7] + 1) - 3/2

blue = RGBColor[17.6/100, 41.6/100, 63.1/100];
yellow = RGBColor[96.9/100, 68.6/100, 20.8/100];

u10 = Plot[fx[x], {x, -15, 15}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "fx(x)"}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[0.5], blue], Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, {Directive[Opacity[0.75], yellow], Directive[Opacity[0.5], yellow]}}}]

u11 = Show[u10, Frame -> False, Axes -> True,  AxesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[0.3], 6, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], ImageSize -> 120, TicksStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[0.3], 5, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]]

Export[FileNameJoin[{HomeDirectory[],"u11.pdf"}], u11]
```

The problem with generated image is that only leftmost filling area is properly rendered. The central and the rightmost areas **go slightly beyond the borders**. The mismatch is not large, around one line-width, but visible. I attach below the generated image converted from pdf to png with 1200pt resolution.

[image: 1200ptx800pt]

**Notice**

This is not an artefact of pdf viewers: Adobe Acrobat 8 Professional, Adobe Reader X (Windows); Preview, Adobe Illustrator CS6, Adobe Acrobat 10.1.9 (Mac) consistently produce the same picture. Preview generates some more artefacts, however, it is not important in this context.

The problem seems to be specific for Mathematica 9.0.1 for Mac and Win 7 (64 bit). I can confirm that the problem does not arise for Mathematica 6.0.1 for Win XP. Other users indicate proper rendering with versions 7 and 8.

**Details**

The effect does not depend on the line-style (full, dotted, etc.), on the opacity, plot-type (frame vs axes, list plot vs. plot). 
Reducing the line-width reduces the undesired effect, however, it is not an option for me (as explained in this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47711/preparing-2d-plots-for-publication)).

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix the problem.

Comment: With *Mathematica* 8.0.4 under Windows 7 x64 I get expected precise result without any mismatch (Acrobat 11.0.6).

Comment: Neither do I have this problem using *Mathematica* 7 under Windows 7, viewing the exported file with Foxit Reader 2.2.

Comment: I always forget to specify the Mathematica version. It was Mathematica 9.0.1 for Mac. I am going to try now with Mathematica 6.0.1 for Win XP.

Comment: @Alexey Popkov: Indeed, this problem does not arise with Mathematica 6.0.1 under Win XP. Strange... Back to the future.

Comment: Same problem on 9.01 on Win7 64bit. Uh, and your `Desktop...` directory will not work (again) with all systems.

Comment: @Yves Klett: Oh, I kindly apologise. I will make path corrections now.

Comment: @Yves Klett: :)

Comment: Working perfectly on _v8.0.4_ Linux.

Comment: Confirm the problem with 9.0.1 on Mac 10.9.2

Comment: By coincidence I just came across another PDF rendering bug in V9. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47821/how-to-fix-a-pdf-line-rendering-problem-in-v9

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This bug has been fixed as of version 10.0. The current result is

[image]

(used *Mathematica* 10.2 on OS X, but other platforms also seem fine)