# How to fix a PDF line rendering problem in V9

Tags: graphics, export, bugs, version-9

If I run this in V8

```
Export["test.pdf", Grid[
  Table[x, {10}, {7}],
  Alignment -> {{Left, {Right}}, Center},
  Background -> {None, White},
  BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times", 12],
  Dividers -> {{1 -> White, -1 -> White}, {3 -> True, 
     6 -> True, -1 -> True}},
  Frame -> False,
  FrameStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[0.5], Black],
  ItemSize -> {{35, {9}}, 1.5},
  ItemStyle -> {Automatic, {Bold}},
  Spacings -> {{1, 1, {0.5}, 2}, {0.5}}]]
```

I get divider lines of the correct thickness. If I run it in V9 the divider line thickness is screwed up. With not only the lines being different to the specification but the line thicknesses vary from each other despite all being specified to have the same thickness.

Coincidentally I have noticed this the same day as [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47777/strange-filling) was posted. It appears something became broken in V9. I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions for fixes?

I am using Mac 10.9.2 and V9.0.1 and V8.0.4

Comment: Confirm the same problem in V9.0.1 on Windows. Different default thicknesses (including `Thickness` rather than `AbsoluteThickness`, or the keyword `Thin`) have similar problems. This strikes me as being a bug.

Comment: @Verbeia I have tagged it as a bug. It wasn't there in V8 so has to be bug introduced in v9. I have also contacted tech support and will update when i hear back from them.

Comment: Will exporting to EPS then converting it to PDF (by some third party tools like ps2pdf) solve your problem? On my Windows 8 and mma 9 it works.

Comment: Can confirm that exporting to EPS works on Mac with Mma 9

Comment: **Appears to be fixed in version 10.**