# How to control frame thickness in Grid object exported to .pdf?

Tags: export, notebooks, grid-layouts, pdf-format

I would like to export a *Grid* object to a .pdf document (preferably as part of a notebook). Here's an example:

```
data = Notebook[
   {Cell[
     BoxData[
      ToBoxes[
       Grid[
        {
         {11, 22},
         {33, 44}
         },
        Frame -> All,
        FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.1], Orange]
        ](* end of Grid *)
       ]
      ]
     ](* end of Cell *)
    }];

Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "grid.pdf", data];
SystemOpen[NotebookDirectory[] <> "grid.pdf"];
```

However, setting thickness of a grid in *FrameStyle* has little to do with the outcoming table (only the upper line is ok).

I've encountered a similar problem concerning *Dividers* here:

[How to fix a PDF line rendering problem in V9](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47821/how-to-fix-a-pdf-line-rendering-problem-in-v9)

They say it's a bug appearing in MMA9 only (MMA8 is free of this problem. Sadly, it's not the version I get to use). Possible solution would be to export a *Notebook* to .eps first, and then convert it to .pdf, which works for simple examples, however there are two reasons I can't use it.

First - as I try to export my *Notebook* to .eps, Mathematica crashes and quits to Windows (i use XP 32bit SP3). Secondly - I'd very much appreciate, if using programs other than MMA could be avoided.

Is there another way of exporting a *Notebook* to .pdf? Or meybe there's some unknown global option which can prevent aliasing? I will be grateful for any help.

PS The thickness is broken only in .pdf - the notebook looks ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rasterizing is a possibility:

```
data = Notebook[{Cell[
     BoxData[ToBoxes[
       Rasterize[
        Grid[{{11, 22}, {33, 44}}, Frame -> All, 
         FrameStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Orange]], 
        ImageResolution -> 400](*end of Grid*)]]](*end of Cell*)}];

Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "grid.pdf"}], data];
SystemOpen[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "grid.pdf"}]];
```

Of course, you don't get scalable graphics this way.  It might be a pain if there are several `Grids` that need rasterizing.  Here it is blown up several times:

```
Import[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "grid.pdf"}], "Images"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**:  Here's an automatic way to convert any `Grid` that contains a thickness directive.  It works in V9.0.1, but the box structure may change in future.  (The problem seems to be fixed in V10, in any case.)

```
rasterizeThickness = 
  box : TagBox[_, "Grid"] /; ! FreeQ[box, Thickness | AbsoluteThickness] :> 
   ToBoxes[Rasterize[ToExpression[box, StandardForm], ImageResolution -> 400]];

Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "grid.pdf"}], data /. rasterizeThickness];
SystemOpen[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "grid.pdf"}]];
```