# Possible bug with ticks with superscripts, Labeled and Export to PDF

Tags: plotting, bugs, mac-os-x

Here is the minimal working example that gives me problems with Mathematica 10.4 on OSX

```
Labeled[LogLogPlot[x, {x, 10^-5, 1}], "Test"]
Export["test.pdf", %]
Export["test.png", %%]
```

In the PDF output, there is a mismatch in the alignment of the ticks labels of the x axis with a superscript `10^-5` and `10^-4` compared to the other labels.

If I export only the plot, without using `Labeled`, the PDF is correct.

Here is the (correct) PNG image

[image: test.png]

Here is the PDF with misplaced ticks labels

[image: test.pdf]

Can anybody reproduce it? Any possible workaround?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the problem as I do not see any misalignment. There is a difference in the plots in size and that is probably why you have 10^-5 on the vertical axis in the bottom plot but otherwise I cannot see any difference.

Comment: @leosenko sorry, I'll edit the question to make the point clearer. The misalignment is in the x axis labels. Notice that the two labels with the exponent are higher than the others in the PDF.

Comment: I can see it now. I can reproduce it as well in Mathematica 10.0.2.

Comment: It does work correctly on Windows 10 - Mathematica 10.4.

Comment: possibly related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47711/preparing-2d-plots-for-publication

Comment: I do reproduce that behavior with OSX and MMA v10.3.1&v10.4.0. Maybe you should add in your post, that this happens only when using `Labeled`.

Comment: With *Mathematica* 10.4 and 8.0.4 on Windows 7 x64 it does work correctly.