# Labeled destroys the log scales in "log" plots when notebook is re-opened

Tags: graphics, bugs, notebooks, ticks, logarithmic-scale

**Bug introduced in 10 or earlier and fixed in 11.1**

---

While testing [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111536/19960) pdf export bug caused by [`Labeled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html), I noticed that this function also destroys the log scales in all "log" plots when you reopen the notebook in which the plots were created.

The problem not only concerns the plots generated by the different **`*Log*`** functions but also those obtained by setting the option **`ScalingFunctions`** to the "Log" mode (see examples below):

For example when you execute:

```
Labeled[LogLogPlot[x, {x, 10^-5, 1}], "Test"]
```

it displays correctly

[image]

but once you save/close/reopen the notebook, this previous plot becomes:

[image]

Here are some other examples showing the same wrong behavior (for me with MMA **v10.3.1, OSX**):

```
LogLogPlot[x, {x, 10^-5, 1}]
Labeled[LogLogPlot[x, {x, 10^-5, 1}], "LogLogPlot"]

LogLinearPlot[Tanh[x], {x, 1, 100}]
Labeled[LogLinearPlot[Tanh[x], {x, 1, 100}], "LogLinearPlot"]

LogPlot[x^x, {x, 1, 5}]
Labeled[LogPlot[x^x, {x, 1, 5}], "LogPlot"]

ListLogPlot[Table[PartitionsQ[n], {n, 50}]]
Labeled[ListLogPlot[Table[PartitionsQ[n], {n, 50}]], "ListLogPlot"]

ListLogLogPlot[Range[20]^3]
Labeled[ListLogLogPlot[Range[20]^3], "ListLogLogPlot"]

Plot[Exp[x], {x, 1, 10}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
Labeled[Plot[Exp[x], {x, 1, 10}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"], "Plot"]

ListPlot[Fibonacci[Range[50]], ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
Labeled[ListPlot[Fibonacci[Range[50]], 
  ScalingFunctions -> "Log"], "ListPlot"]

gh = Histogram[
  VertexDegree[RandomGraph[BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution[10^4, 3]]],
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
Labeled[gh, "Histogram"]
```

In **v10.4.0** however, the problem does not occur anymore for [`ListLogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLogPlot.html), [`ListLogLogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLogLogPlot.html) and [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html). The problem was probably noticed while adding `Labeled` as a new possible wrapper for the datas (see the corresponding documentations), maybe involving a redesign of these functions ...

The only workaround (as originally proposed by @Algohi) seem to be to wrap the whole `Labeled` expression with `Dynamic`.

I also notice that:

- you can copy/paste the "wrong" plot, to get back the original correct plot.
- you can wrap the plot in `GraphicsGrid` (`GraphicsRow`, ...) to prevent the log scale to be destroyed. However this is not a very useful workaround as the final plot has extra margins which I was not able to get rid of.

Comment: It's a bug indeed. The key difference between `ListLogLogPlot` and `LogLogPlot` (in version 10.4) is that `ListLogLogPlot`'s output contains explicit `Ticks` specification while `LogLogPlot` contains functional (`Dynamic`) specification. Added the `bugs` tag.

Comment: It is interesting that if we copy the `InputForm` of `LogLogPlot` wrapped by `Labeled` from *Mathematica* 10.4 to 8.0.4 and then evaluate and save, the generated plot looks OK when opened with version 10.4. But if we evaluate the code in version 10.4 again and save, the bug appears again after reopening both with version 8.0.4 and 10.4. So the underlying bug seems to be present already in version 8.0.4 but doesn't manifestate due to some difference in the corresponding `BoxData`.

Comment: The key difference in the `BoxData` between version 8.0.4 and 10.4 is that in version 8.0.4 it contains *cached* explicit `Ticks` specification in the form ``Ticks -> FrontEndValueCache[{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}]}, {{{-13.122363377404328`, FormBox[InterpretationBox[StyleBox[
            GraphicsBox[{}, ImageSize -> {0., 0.}, BaselinePosition -> Baseline], "CacheGraphics" -> False], 
           Spacer[{0., 0.}]], TraditionalForm], {0.005, 0.}, {
          Thickness[0.001]}},`` <...> while in version 10.4 it doesn't.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It seems the bug has been fixed since v11.1.0 (I am on OSX). Can you confirm ?

Comment: I confirm that the problem is absent in version 11.1.1 on Windows 7 x64. In version 11.0.1 on the same machine it is present, so the bug seems to be fixed in version 11.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The workaround [suggested by Algohi](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112077/280) works but it leads to reevaluation of the entire `LogLogPlot` each time you open a Notebook. The following workaround avoids this:

```
With[{g = Labeled[LogLogPlot[x, {x, 10^-5, 1}], "Test"]}, Dynamic@g]
```

Another workaround is to place this `Graphics` as `Inset` inside of another `Graphics` object:

```
pl = LogLogPlot[x, {x, 10^-5, 1}];
Labeled[Graphics[{Inset[pl, Center, Center, Scaled[1]]}, 
  Options[pl, {AspectRatio, ImageSize}]], "LogLogPlot"]
```

(the correct ticks will be generated only after you click the <kbd>Enable Dynamics</kbd> button after opening the Notebook).

The essence of the bug is that FrontEnd does not update functional (i.e. `Dynamic`) `Ticks` specification when `Graphics` is enclosed by `Labeled`. The bug doesn't reveal itself in older *Mathematica* versions seemingly because in those versions the `BoxData` of the output `Cell` in the Notebook contains cached explicit `Ticks` specification produced during first-time rendering of the output by the FrontEnd (the following is a truncated version of that specification generated by version 8.0.4):

```
Ticks -> FrontEndValueCache[{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
    Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}]}, {{{-13.122363377404328`, 
     FormBox[InterpretationBox[
       StyleBox[GraphicsBox[{}, ImageSize -> {0., 0.}, BaselinePosition -> Baseline], 
        "CacheGraphics" -> False], Spacer[{0., 0.}]], TraditionalForm], {0.005, 
      0.}, {Thickness[0.001]}},
```

When `Graphics` is wrapped by `Labeled` *Mathematica* 10 (as opposed to version 8.0.4) doesn't generate this cache. And it is still ignoring functional `Ticks` specification when `Graphics` is wrapped by `Labeled`.

Comment: I actually was digging exactly in the same direction at the time you posted your first comment yesterday ;) Also, I don't get what you exactly mean in the last sentence. What I observe is that `Labeled` prevents the ticks cache (`FrontEndValueCache`) to be generated (as it is normally the case for all plots without `Labeled`). In v10.4, they seem to have redesigned some functions (see my updated post), and the cache isn't generated anymore but ticks are explicitly given.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and update in the question. I have corrected my answer and added another workaround based on you findings with `GraphicsGrid`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov that is great. Could explain how does that first trick (`With[...`) happen, I am not sure I fully understand it.

Comment: @Algohi The trick is simply to pre-evaluate `LogLogPlot` and then pass the result to `Dynamic`. So `Dynamic` won't evaluate `LogLogPlot` because it contains the final result of the evaluation. The same can be done shorter as `Dynamic @@ {Labeled[LogLogPlot[x, {x, 10^-5, 1}], "Test"]}`.

Comment: Aha, I got it. It is more clear when you look at `FullForm` of the plot. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`LogLogPlot` plots contain a dynamic objects which when you open the notebook, the security of Mathematica prevents the dynamic objects from being updated. Check [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NotebookSecurity.html)

What you can do is wrap your plot with dynamic and when opened again and when you click Enable Dynamic, you will get the correct plot.

```
Dynamic@Labeled[LogLogPlot[x, {x, 10^-5, 1}], "Test"]
```

Comment: Your workaround works but do you have so more detailed explanation ? If `LogLogPlot` is used without `Labeled` no problem then. So `Labeled` prevents this dynamic updating ? Anyway, this is not the expected behavior.