# ListLogPlot fails if Dynamic Updating not enabled - Ticks specification?

Tags: plotting, dynamic, ticks

MMA 11.0.1.0 Win 10 64 bit; MWE

```
ListLogPlot[Exp[Range[10]]]
```

With Dynamic Updating Enabled, result is correct. Without it MMA complains "Tick specification must be a list or a function" and the result is this

[image]

If Dynamic Updating is then enabled, or the graphic is saved to disk, the plot appears correctly.

ListPlot in place of ListLogPlot does not show this behaviour.

Smells like a bug - or is there a sound reason for this behaviour?

[It was doubly - or squared? - unfortunate that I hit this on my first use of ListLogPlot when I was also using custom ticks for the first time; I did not question the basic function for rather a long time]

Comment: Somethings does indeed seem broken here - consider also `ListPlot[Exp[Range[10]], ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]`, which doesn't generate an error, but simply shows wrong ticks. Also, [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112068/labeled-destroys-the-log-scales-in-log-plots-when-notebook-is-re-opened) seems related

Comment: It happens because it is the FrontEnd which generates base ticks but it can't rescale them/their positions so they are sent to Kernel and back etc. This communication is not possible when dynamic updating is disabled. Either the design is completely wrong or there is a bug in implementation which should not use the preemptive link for this exchange.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for confirming that there is some kind of problem; some recent Windows update (probably) leaves the front end unresponsive for ~5s at a time, in some way related to graphics I think, so I disabled Dynamic Updating, which *seemed* to improve things - but this was an unexpected side effect. Curious about how you knew the cause; should you wish to make your comment into an answer I'll accept - my thanks either way.