# BarLegend can't make spaced contours when contours number>11

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

According to Document of BarLegend,BarLegend will select equally spaced contours:

> BarLegend[cf,contours]
>   generates a legend that identifies color
>   ranges from the color function cf based on the set of contours

However, when I try something like:

```
BarLegend["LakeColors", #] & /@ Range[8, 13] // Row
```

the output：

[image]

the figure of spaced contours disappear when contours number>11. Why will this happen?how to avoid this and get spaced contours?
I use Mathematica9 on Win7

Comment: From the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html), "BarLegend[cf,contours] may use a list of colors or a continuous spectrum depending on the density of contour values." So, this is as designed.

Comment: Ahhh~~Then is there anyway to disable the "continuous spectrum"?

Comment: There might be a hidden option for it, but I can't seem to find one.

Comment: It'd be helpful if the v10 BarLegend had an option to specify the color density separate from the tick density versus assuming it based on the # of ticks.  Changes to the v10 BarLegend affected me the opposite way where I wanted a continuous color gradient with less than 11 ticks but the BarLegend kept returning a segmented color gradient.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
makeContours[barLegend_BarLegend] /; (Length[barLegend] =!= 2) := barLegend

makeContours[barLegend_BarLegend] := 
 Module[{colorScheme = barLegend[[1]], contourCount = barLegend[[2]]},
  If[IntegerQ[contourCount] && contourCount > 11 && 
    DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemeNameQ[colorScheme], 
   ToExpression[
    MakeBoxes[barLegend] /. 
      RasterBox[colors_, scale_] :> 
       RasterBox[List@*List @@@ ColorData[colorScheme] /@ Subdivide[contourCount], scale] /. 
      (InterpretationFunction :> _) -> (InterpretationFunction :> (# &))],
   barLegend]]

makeContours@BarLegend["LakeColors", #] & /@ Range[8, 20] // Row
```

[image: OUT]

Comment: well done! I feel like I should delete my answer now, but it does contain some interesting information about the hidden options underlying this.

Comment: @Verbeia Thanks. You should definitely keep your answer posted. It not only contains interesting informations about additional options, but also how one might try to change the way `BarLegend` is created, although that seems to be the tougher road in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Although there are hidden options to the underlying function (`` Charting`iBarLegend ``) that seem to address the required functionality, there does not seem to be any way to get the user-exposed function `BarLegend` to react to them. The following did not change the presentation of the test cases you provided, and neither did attempts to pass some promising-sounding options directly through `BarLegend`. For example the following did not change anything:

```
BarLegend["LakeColors", 12, "SmoothRange" -> False]
```

I suspect that there is no way to get the desired effect in current versions of Mathematica using straightforward options, though I could be wrong. And as Karsten's excellent answer shows, it is possible to force the issue by constructing the raster manually.

```
SetOptions[Charting`iBarLegend, ShowContours -> True]

{ColorFunctionScaling -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Automatic, 
 ImageSizeAction -> Automatic, RoundingRadius -> Automatic, 
 FrameStyle -> Automatic, Alignment -> Automatic, 
 Spacings -> Automatic, Scrollbars -> False, ScrollPosition -> {0, 0},
  Background -> Automatic, ContentPadding -> True, 
 DefaultLabelStyle -> {}, "Orientation" -> "Column", 
 Charting`AxesLabelRotate -> True, Charting`AxisAnnotation -> None, 
 Charting`AxisFactor -> None, Charting`AxisAppearance -> Automatic, 
 Charting`AxisLabel -> None, Charting`LabelSide -> Automatic, 
 Charting`PadLabels -> Automatic, Charting`RotateLabels -> False, 
 Charting`TickAnnotations -> None, Charting`TickSide -> Automatic, 
 Charting`TickLabels -> Automatic, Charting`TickLengths -> Automatic, 
 Charting`TickMarkers -> Automatic, Charting`TickWrappers -> None, 
 Charting`RotateTicks -> 0, AxesLabel -> None, AxesStyle -> Automatic,
  Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Automatic, 
 LabelingFunction -> Automatic, Ticks -> Automatic, 
 TicksStyle -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, Identity}, BaseStyle -> {}, 
 "LegendMethod" -> "Fixed", "Density" -> "Continuous", 
 "SmoothRange" -> True, "AxesPriority" -> Automatic, 
 "Sorting" -> True, "ContourMethod" -> "Graphics", 
 "RenderMode" -> Automatic, "LegendItemLayout" -> Automatic, 
 "PinningPoint" -> None, "StyledContours" -> None, 
 "ShowContours" -> True, PlotTheme -> "Mathematica"}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's probably obvious to people with more experience than I, but since it took me a while to figure out:

If you want to modify Karsten's excellent answer above to produce horizontal BarLegends you need to take three inputs, transpose the matrix used in RasterBox, and add the LegendLayout->Row option to the function call:

```
makeContours[barLegend_BarLegend] /; (Length[barLegend] =!= 3) := barLegend

makeContours[barLegend_BarLegend] := 
Module[{colorScheme = barLegend[[1]], contourCount = barLegend[[2]]},
  If[IntegerQ[contourCount] && contourCount > 11 && 
    DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemeNameQ[colorScheme], 
   ToExpression[
    MakeBoxes[barLegend] /. 
      RasterBox[colors_, scale_] :> 
       RasterBox[Transpose[List@*List @@@ 
      ColorData[colorScheme] /@ Subdivide[contourCount]], 
     scale] /. (InterpretationFunction :> _) -> \
    (InterpretationFunction :> (# &))], barLegend]]

 makeContours@BarLegend["LakeColors", #, LegendLayout -> "Row"] & /@ 
 Range[8, 20] // Row
```

[image: horizontal BarLegends]

One additional note. If in OS X you export one of these bar legends to pdf, the discrete color blocks will disappear and you'll be back to a smooth gradient. Frustrating! This is because of a bug in Mathematica's pdf export, described here along with the unfortunate solution: [PDF exports of ArrayPlot's are fuzzy (OS X)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11273/pdf-exports-of-arrayplots-are-fuzzy-os-x/66026#66026) .

Answer (score 2):

### Analysis

In *Mathematica* 10.1 this is hard-coded in `` Legending`LegendDump`iColorBandLegend ``.

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

PrintDefinitions @ Legending`LegendDump`iColorBandLegend
```

wherein appears:

```
cthreshold = 11
```

and later:

```
vdensity =
  If[vnumberofticks > cthreshold || moptShowContours === None, 200, cnumber - 1]
```

It happens that this function hands off to yet another internal function:

```
PrintDefinitions @ Legending`LegendDump`iColorGradientLegend
```

But in doing so it passes the density value as a `Method` option, and in `iColorGradientLegend` the `Method` supersedes other options.  So we're going to have to modify something to get around this. `iColorBandLegend` seems like the obvious choice as it is the origin of the problem.

### Patch

```
BarLegend[] // ToBoxes;  (* preload; do not remove! *)

With[{dv := DownValues[Legending`LegendDump`iColorBandLegend]},
  dv = dv /. HoldPattern[cth : Legending`LegendDump`cthreshold = _] :> (cth = 35);
]
```

Test:

```
BarLegend["LakeColors", #] & /@ Range[8, 16] // Row
```

[image]