# Contours aren't aligned with frame ticks in ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

Because of the problem described in [BarLegend can't make spaced contours when contours number>11](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85444/barlegend-cant-make-spaced-contours-when-contours-number11), I decided to brew my homemade spaced-contours-barlegend. After some trials I get something like this(combined with `Row[{plapla, code-below}]`):

```
ContourPlot[y, {x, 0, .2}, {y, 0, 1}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Purple, Blue, Green, Orange, Red, 
  Red}, #] &), Contours -> 17, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
FrameTicks -> {{None, {#, 180*# + 60, {0, 0.6}} & /@ 
 Range[0, 1, 2/18]}, {None, None}}, 
FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, 20], 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick], AspectRatio -> 16, ImageSize -> 80]
```

which produce:

[image]

It looks OK at a glance, but I noticed that there is **slightly disalignment between the contours and the frame ticks**. Why is this happening? How can I avoid it?

Comment: Use `Contours -> Range[0, 1, 1/18]` to force equal spacing.

Comment: Note that `Length[Range[0, 1, 2/18]]` is $\ne 17+2$, so therein lies your mismatch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of providing the number of contours you want with the option `Contours` you should provide the values at which you want contours. When using this with a contour plot that uses the same color scheme, you should provide the same values for contours to the contour plot, or you may end up with a mismatch between your legend and the plot.

```
ContourPlot[y, {x, 0, .2}, {y, 0, 1}
 , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
 , ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Purple, Blue, Green, Orange, Red, 
      Red}, #] &)
 , Contours -> Range[0, 1, 1/18]
 , PlotRangePadding -> 0
 , Frame -> True
 , Axes -> False
 , FrameTicks -> {{None, {#, 180*# + 60, {0, 0.6}} & /@ 
     Range[0, 1, 2/18]}, {None, None}}
 , FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, 20], 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick]
 , AspectRatio -> 16, ImageSize -> 80
 ]
```

Gives:

[image]