# How to change the Bar chart in contour plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, charts, plot-themes

I created a contour plot from my data, the first image below shows the bar chart which I am getting but I need it to look like the second image (I created by paint) the first number should start from zero and go up one by one, how can I do that?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want discrete steps or a continuous gradient?

Comment: Discrete, distance between each step should be 1.

Comment: I that case you are going to run into this issue: [(85444)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85444/121)

Answer (score 0):

With `BarLegend` patched according to [BarLegend can't make spaced contours when contours number>11](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85444/121#138864) please try:

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 13}}, Range[0, 13]]
```

Or:

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 13}}, Range[0, 12, 1/2]]
```